# How to concatenate an int in c

Tags: c

So I have this code

```
char str[80] = "192.168.12.142";
char string[80];
char s[2] = ".";
char *token;
int val[4];
int counter=0;
/* get the first token */
token = strtok(str, s);

/* walk through other tokens */
while( token != NULL ){

  val[counter] = atoi(token);
  token = strtok(NULL, s);
  counter++;
}


sprintf(string,"%d.%d.%d.%d",val[0],val[1],val[2],val[3]);
puts(string);
```

Instead of concatenate it into an string, **I want to concatenate it to an int concatenation**, is there any possibly alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by "int concatenation"? Can you explain what you want the result to look like?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that int concatenation means: `int_cat(12, 34, 56) = 123456`?

Comment: Hint: multiply by 10 and add number you want to concatenate.

Comment: Are you trying to create an integer that contains the 32bit binary representation of an IPv4 address?

Comment: If you mean building a uint32_t from 4 uint8_t, than use multiply/bit-shift and add/bit-or.

Comment: If you are trying to convert an IPv4 address into its integer representation, use a pre-existing function for that, such as `inet_addr()` or `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: Your variable names `string`, `str`, and `s` make your code more difficult to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, what you seem to do is exactly what `inet_aton` is doing. You might consider using this function.

Regarding the concatenation you can write

```
int result = (val[3] << 24) | (val[2] << 16) | (val[1] << 8) | (val[0]);
```

or, for the opposite byte order:

```
int result = (val[0] << 24) | (val[1] << 16) | (val[2] << 8) | (val[3]);
```

Comment: +1 Minor: for portability, better to use `long` rather than `int`.  Further suggest `unsigned`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
(((((val[0] << 8) + val[1]) << 8) + val[2]) << 8 ) + val[3]
```

Or equivalently

```
(val[0] << 24) | (val[1] << 16) | (val[2] << 8) | val[0]
```